# Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.(Sqlite)

Tags: c#, unity3d, sqlite

```
Cancelling DisplayDialog because it was run from a thread that is not the main thread: Opening file failed Opening file D:/Unity/terranetools.git/Assets/TerrainTools/db/object.sqlite: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возникает ошибка доступа к БД. Вполне вероятно из-за одновременного обращения к одному файлу. Как лучше обращаться к SQLite в Unity, если соединение уже открыто?

Мой файл подключение к базе:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static public class ObjectDataBase
{
    static public string connectionString;

    static public void GetSettings(out bool outEditModeBool, out string outPrefabForEditing, out float outmapoffsetx, out float outmapoffsetz, out string outstringObjfileURL)
    {
        connectionString = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/TerrainTools/db/object.sqlite";
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT EditModeBool,PrefabForEditing,mapoffsetx,mapoffsetz,ObjfileURL FROM Setting";
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    bool tempEditModeBool = false;
                    string tempPrefabForEditing = "yesnull";
                    float tempmapoffsetx = 0.0f;
                    float tempmapoffsetz = 0.0f;
                    string temstringObjfileURL = "yesnull";
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        tempEditModeBool = reader.GetBoolean(0);
                        tempPrefabForEditing = reader.GetString(1);
                        tempmapoffsetx = (float)reader.GetDouble(2);
                        tempmapoffsetz = (float)reader.GetDouble(3);
                        temstringObjfileURL = reader.GetString(4);
                    }
                    outEditModeBool = tempEditModeBool;
                    outPrefabForEditing = tempPrefabForEditing;
                    outmapoffsetx = tempmapoffsetx;
                    outmapoffsetz = tempmapoffsetz;
                    outstringObjfileURL = temstringObjfileURL;
                    dbConnection.Close();
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static public void GetCreatingReliefSettings(out LoadTerrainRaw.CreatingReliefSettings outCreatingReliefSettings)
    {
        connectionString = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/TerrainTools/db/object.sqlite";
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT AmountX,AmountY,TerrainWidth,TerrainLenght,TerrainHeight,HeightmapResoltion,PrimitiveToCreate_ID,DetailResolution,DetailResolutionPerPatch,ControlTextureResolution,BaseTextureReolution,Path FROM CreatingReliefSettings";
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    outCreatingReliefSettings = new LoadTerrainRaw.CreatingReliefSettings();
                    outCreatingReliefSettings.tileAmount = Vector2.one;
                    outCreatingReliefSettings.widthTerrain = 2000f;
                    outCreatingReliefSettings.lenghtTerrain = 2000f;
                    outCreatingReliefSettings.heightTerrain = 168f;
                    outCreatingReliefSettings.heightmapResoltion = 65;
                    outCreatingReliefSettings.Depth = 1;
                    outCreatingReliefSettings.detailResolution = 2048;
                    outCreatingReliefSettings.detailResolutionPerPatch = 8;
                    outCreatingReliefSettings.controlTextureResolution = 2048;
                    outCreatingReliefSettings.baseTextureResolution = 2048;
                    outCreatingReliefSettings.path = string.Empty;

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        outCreatingReliefSettings.tileAmount = new Vector2((float)reader.GetDouble(0), (float)reader.GetDouble(1));
                        outCreatingReliefSettings.widthTerrain = (float)reader.GetDouble(2);
                        outCreatingReliefSettings.lenghtTerrain = (float)reader.GetDouble(3);
                        outCreatingReliefSettings.heightTerrain = (float)reader.GetDouble(4);
                        outCreatingReliefSettings.heightmapResoltion = reader.GetInt16(5);
                        outCreatingReliefSettings.Depth = reader.GetInt16(6);
                        outCreatingReliefSettings.detailResolution = reader.GetInt16(7);
                        outCreatingReliefSettings.detailResolutionPerPatch = reader.GetInt16(8);
                        outCreatingReliefSettings.controlTextureResolution = reader.GetInt16(9);
                        outCreatingReliefSettings.baseTextureResolution = reader.GetInt16(10);
                        outCreatingReliefSettings.path = reader.GetString(11);
                    }
                    dbConnection.Close();
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static public Dictionary<int, string> GetAllTypeGeometry()
    {
        connectionString = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/TerrainTools/db/object.sqlite";
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM TypeGeometry";
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    Dictionary<int, string> countriesTypeG = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // Debug.Log(reader.GetString(1)+" id:"+reader.GetInt16(0));
                        countriesTypeG.Add(reader.GetInt16(0), reader.GetString(1));
                    }
                    dbConnection.Close();
                    reader.Close();
                    return countriesTypeG;
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Немножко кодревью. Методы надо писать так, чтоб они относились к одному из 2-х типов: Метод-Запрос - метод возвращающий результат и Метод-Команда - метод возвращает void и выполняет какое-то действие для смены состояния класса или др. Такой же метод `void GetSettings(out bool outEditModeBool, out string outPrefabForEditing, out float outmapoffsetx, out float outmapoffsetz, out string outstringObjfileURL)` - это страх и ужас. Создайте класс или структуру и возвращайте результат запроса к базе в виде экземпляра с нужными свойствами. Вы про DTO слышали когда-нибудь?

Comment: Bulson про DTO слышал. Это чужой код который я правлю. Пытаюсь навести лоск и красоту. Хочу найти способ минимальными силами, сделать максимально возможный результат

Comment: @Bulson Переделал подключение к БД , но ошибка осталась https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1080769/178835

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Совет один и общий - попробуйте отладить свой код. Судя по тому классу, который вы демонстрируете - одновременного обращения к файлу быть не может, так как код у вас последовательный и синхронный.

Но ошибка, которую вы ловите в коде скорее всего возникает потому, что где-то в коде вы создаете соединение с базой, а далее его просто забываете закрыть. Потом пытаетесь открыть это соединение снова, и получаете исключение.

Кроме того, у вас в каждом методе в самом конце вызывается код а ля:

```
 dbConnection.Close();
 reader.Close();
```

Который вызывать совершенно не нужно и возможно даже в этом часть вашей ошибки. Дело в том, что оператор `using (...)` можно использовать только с классами, которые реализуют интерфейс `IDisposable`, который содержит 1 метод - `Dispose()`. Тело этого метода содержит как раз закрытие всех управляемых ресурсов. Этот метод автоматически дергается у экземпляра класса, когда выполнение доходит до конца блока `using(...)`.

Вы же в своей последовательности вызовов `.Close()` можете банально ошибиться в порядке вызова (особенно если эти объекты ссылаются друг на друга), что может привести к нежелательным последствиям. В вашем случае, достаточно сложно во всем этом разобраться, потому что у вас вложенность `using(...)` достигает 4.

Возможно, что причина вашей ошибки в том, что файл с бд читается где-то в другом классе, а не в том, что вы привели в вопросе (это нельзя с точностью утверждать, потому что неизвестен весь код проекта). В таком случае обязательно нужно вынести функционал работы с бд в отдельный класс, а не раскидывать его по разным методам и классам.

Чтобы избавиться от надобности поиска пути до бд и доступа к ней на каждый чих - вынесите взаимодействие с бд в отдельный класс, который будет такую работу инкапсулировать. Создайте такой класс в 1 экземпляре и передавайте его другим классам, которые хотят "общаться" с бд. В таком случае открытие/закрытие бд будет всегда внутри 1 класса, который сможет отслеживать уникальность попыток доступа к бд. Кроме того, что вы избавитесь от дублирования функционала, вы также улучшите соблюдение принципов SOLID в вашем коде.

Comment: Вы всё правильно поняли, этот код вызывается в других классах, недаром методы и класс static

Comment: Переделал подключение к БД, но ошибка осталась https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1080769/178835

Answer (score 1):

Надо создать dbConnection один раз при запуске приложения, и один раз закрыть при выходе. А не дергать его много раз. Т.к. при этом можно запросто забыть где-то закрыть.

Например вот этот ваш код:

```
DemoDTO DTOSqliteObj = new DemoDTO();
if (!DTOSqliteObj.checkStatus()) { DTOSqliteObj.openDataBase(); }
myList = DTOSqliteObj.SelectAllObjMap();
DTOSqliteObj.closeDataBase();
```

нужно вызывать не при каждом обращении к базе, тем более, что здесь нужно примерно так (схематично):

```
DemoDTO DTOSqliteObj = new DemoDTO();
DTOSqliteObj.openDataBase();
try
{
    myList = DTOSqliteObj.SelectAllObjMap();
}
finally
{
    DTOSqliteObj.closeDataBase();
}
```

Comment: Надо создать dbConnection один раз при запуске приложения, и один раз закрыть при выходе. А хорошо ли это? В Qt  на C++, на сколько я знаю, правилом хорошего тона считается  :открывать подключение к базе , когда надо и закрывать после того как поработал

Comment: Можно привести пример, как надо ? и using нужен для освобождения неуправляемых ресурсов?

Comment: > Надо создать dbConnection один раз при запуске приложения, и один раз закрыть при выходе. А хорошо ли это? 
--- это решает разработчик приложения, но в данном случае может помочь, т.к. код станет намного проще. А так - да, это другая крайность. У вас на каждый запрос заново создается соединение - это может быть очень непроизводительно.

Comment: Такой способ как у вас больше подходит для веб-сервисов - на каждый запрос к сервису создаем соединение. И то там пулы соединений делают и переиспользуют соединения. А у вас просто приложение юнити, скорее всего подойдет одно соединение на все запросы. Что в этом плохого? Если вдруг надо будет в том же приложении с файлами БД работать напрямую (я так делал), то можно перед этим соединение закрыть.

Comment: using нужен для освобождения неуправляемых ресурсов? -- и управляемых тоже (тут скорее всего неуправляемый), но можно и через try finally (поправлю ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Переделал подключение к БД, но ошибка осталась.

Вызываю в коде любое обращение к БД так:

```
    DemoDTO DTOSqliteObj = new DemoDTO();
    if (!DTOSqliteObj.checkStatus()) { DTOSqliteObj.openDataBase(); }
    myList = DTOSqliteObj.SelectAllObjMap();
    DTOSqliteObj.closeDataBase();
```

Три файла для подключения к БД(DTO.cs):

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DEMO.Common
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the base class for all DataTransferObjects.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class DTO
    {
        public static string connectionString = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/TerrainTools/db/object.sqlite";
        public IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
        public IDbCommand dbCmd;
        public IDataReader reader;

        public DTO()
        {

        }

        public bool openDataBase()
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            if (dbConnection.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool checkStatus()
        {
            if (dbConnection.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (dbConnection.State.ToString() == "Closed")
            {
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public bool closeDataBase()
        {
            dbConnection.Close();
            reader.Close();
            if (dbConnection.State.ToString() == "Closed")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

DTOSerializerHelper.cs:

```
using System;
// using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace DEMO.Common
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for DTOSerializerHelper.
    /// </summary>
    public class DTOSerializerHelper
    {
        public DTOSerializerHelper()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates xml string from given dto.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dto">DTO</param>
        /// <returns>XML</returns>
        public static DTO SerializeDTO(DTO dto, string sqlQuery)
        {
            try
            {
                dto.dbCmd = dto.dbConnection.CreateCommand();
                dto.dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                dto.reader = dto.dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
                return dto;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Propogate the exception.
                throw ex;
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DemoDTO.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using System;
// using System.Xml.Serialization;
using DEMO.Common;


using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;

public class DemoDTO : DTO
{
    public DemoDTO()
    {
    }

    public SattingMain GetSettings(SattingMain mainSatting)
    {
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT EditModeBool,PrefabForEditing,mapoffsetx,mapoffsetz,ObjfileURL FROM Setting";
        DTO dto = DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQuery);
        while (dto.reader.Read())
        {
            mainSatting.EditModeBool = dto.reader.GetBoolean(0);
            mainSatting.PrefabForEditing = dto.reader.GetString(1);
            mainSatting.mapoffsetx = (float)dto.reader.GetDouble(2);
            mainSatting.mapoffsetz = (float)dto.reader.GetDouble(3);
            mainSatting.stringObjfileURL = dto.reader.GetString(4);
        }
        return mainSatting;
    }


    public bool updateSQLite(string sqlQueryStringUpdateObj)
    {
        if (DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQueryStringUpdateObj) != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public List<int> SELECT_id(int id, string str)
    {
        List<int> listINT = new List<int>();
        string sqlQueryDelete = "";
        if (str == "Prefabs")
        {
            sqlQueryDelete = "SELECT id_Prefabs FROM Connection_ObjMap_Prefabs WHERE id_ObjMap = " + id + "";
        }
        else if (str == "Textures")
        {
            sqlQueryDelete = "SELECT id_Textures FROM Connection_ObjMap_Textures WHERE id_ObjMap = " + id + "";
        }
        if (sqlQueryDelete != "")
        {
            DTO dto = DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQueryDelete);
            if (dto != null)
            {
                while (dto.reader.Read())
                {
                    int tempint = -1;
                    if (str == "Prefabs")
                    {
                        if (!dto.reader.IsDBNull(dto.reader.GetOrdinal("id_Prefabs")))
                        {
                            tempint = dto.reader.GetInt16(0);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (str == "Textures")
                    {
                        if (!dto.reader.IsDBNull(dto.reader.GetOrdinal("id_Textures")))
                        {
                            tempint = dto.reader.GetInt16(0);
                        }
                    }
                    if (tempint != -1)
                    {
                        listINT.Add(tempint);
                    }
                }
                return listINT;
            }
            else
            {
                listINT = null;
                return listINT;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            listINT = null;
            return listINT;
        }
    }

    public bool DeleteAllid_ObjMapPrefabs(int id_ObjMap)
    {
        string sqlQueryDelete = "DELETE FROM Connection_ObjMap_Prefabs WHERE id_ObjMap = " + id_ObjMap + "";
        if (DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQueryDelete) != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }



    public bool DeleteAllid_ObjMapTextures(int id_ObjMap)
    {
        string sqlQueryDelete = "DELETE FROM Connection_ObjMap_Textures WHERE id_ObjMap = " + id_ObjMap + "";
        if (DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQueryDelete) != null)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int tempintone = -1;
                int tempinttwo = -1;
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("id_ObjMap")))
                {
                    tempintone = reader.GetInt16(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    tempintone = -1;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public long INSERTSELECTObj(string sqlQueryINSERT)
    {
        DTO dto = DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQueryINSERT);
        if (dto != null)
        {
            using (IDbCommand dbCmdLastID = dto.dbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                dbCmdLastID.CommandText = "SELECT last_insert_rowid()";
                long lastID = (long)dbCmdLastID.ExecuteScalar();
                lastID.ToString();
                return lastID;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public bool CheckRecordCheckInt(int intone, int inttwo)
    {
        string sqlQuerySELECT = "SELECT id_ObjMap,id_Prefabs FROM Connection_ObjMap_Prefabs";
        DTO dto = DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQuerySELECT);
        if (dto != null)
        {
            bool boolvalue = false;
            while (dto.reader.Read())
            {
                int tempintone = -1;
                int tempinttwo = -1;
                if (!dto.reader.IsDBNull(dto.reader.GetOrdinal("id_ObjMap")))
                {
                    tempintone = reader.GetInt16(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    tempintone = -1;
                }
                if (!dto.reader.IsDBNull(dto.reader.GetOrdinal("id_Prefabs")))
                {
                    tempinttwo = reader.GetInt16(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    tempinttwo = -1;
                }
                // Debug.Log("intone="+intone+"tempintone="+tempintone+"inttwo="+inttwo+"tempinttwo="+tempinttwo);
                if (tempintone == -1 || tempinttwo == -1)
                {
                    boolvalue = false;
                }
                else if (tempintone == intone && tempinttwo == inttwo)
                {
                    boolvalue = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    boolvalue = false;
                }

            }
            return boolvalue;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int RecordCheckUrl(string stringCheck, string table)
    {
        string sqlQuerySELECT = "";
        if (table == "Prefabs")
        {
            sqlQuerySELECT = "SELECT id_pref,url FROM Prefabs";
        }
        else if (table == "Textures")
        {
            sqlQuerySELECT = "SELECT id_tex,url FROM Textures";
        }
        DTO dto = DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQuerySELECT);
        if (dto != null && sqlQuerySELECT != "")
        {
            int id_pref_temp = -1;
            bool checkBOOL = false;
            int count = 0;
            while (dto.reader.Read())
            {
                string url_temp = "null";
                if (!dto.reader.IsDBNull(dto.reader.GetOrdinal("url")))
                {
                    url_temp = dto.reader.GetString(1);
                    if (url_temp == stringCheck)
                    {
                        if (table == "Prefabs")
                        {
                            if (!dto.reader.IsDBNull(dto.reader.GetOrdinal("id_pref")))
                            {
                                id_pref_temp = dto.reader.GetInt16(0);
                                return id_pref_temp;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                id_pref_temp = -1;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (table == "Textures")
                        {
                            if (!dto.reader.IsDBNull(dto.reader.GetOrdinal("id_tex")))
                            {
                                id_pref_temp = dto.reader.GetInt16(0);
                                return id_pref_temp;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                id_pref_temp = -1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Debug.Log("url_temp="+reader.GetString(1));
                }
                else
                {
                    url_temp = "null";
                    // Debug.Log("url_temp=null");
                }
                if (stringCheck == url_temp)
                {
                    checkBOOL = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    checkBOOL = false;
                }
                count++;
            }
            if (count == 0) { checkBOOL = true; id_pref_temp = -2; }
            if (checkBOOL == true) { } else { id_pref_temp = -1; }
            return id_pref_temp;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<int, string> GetAllTypeGeometry()
    {
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT gtype_id,gtype_name FROM TypeGeometry";
        DTO dto = DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQuery);
        if (dto != null)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> countriesTypeG = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            while (dto.reader.Read())
            {
                // Debug.Log(reader.GetString(1)+" id:"+reader.GetInt16(0));
                countriesTypeG.Add(dto.reader.GetInt16(0), dto.reader.GetString(1));
            }
            return countriesTypeG;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<int, string> GetAllLayer()
    {
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT l_id,l_name FROM Layer";
        DTO dto = DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQuery);
        if (dto != null)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> countriesTypeG = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            while (dto.reader.Read())
            {
                // Debug.Log(reader.GetString(1)+" id:"+reader.GetInt16(0));
                countriesTypeG.Add(dto.reader.GetInt16(0), dto.reader.GetString(1));
            }
            return countriesTypeG;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<int, string> GetAllmethod()
    {
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT id,name FROM method";
        DTO dto = DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQuery);
        if (dto != null)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> countriesTypeG = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            while (dto.reader.Read())
            {
                // Debug.Log(reader.GetString(1)+" id:"+reader.GetInt16(0));
                countriesTypeG.Add(dto.reader.GetInt16(0), dto.reader.GetString(1));
            }
            return countriesTypeG;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public LoadTerrainRaw.CreatingReliefSettings GetCreatingReliefSettings(LoadTerrainRaw.CreatingReliefSettings outCreatingReliefSettings)
    {
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT AmountX,AmountY,TerrainWidth,TerrainLenght,TerrainHeight,HeightmapResoltion,PrimitiveToCreate_ID,DetailResolution,DetailResolutionPerPatch,ControlTextureResolution,BaseTextureReolution,Path FROM CreatingReliefSettings";
        DTO dto = DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQuery);
        if (dto != null)
        {
            outCreatingReliefSettings = new LoadTerrainRaw.CreatingReliefSettings();
            outCreatingReliefSettings.tileAmount = Vector2.one;
            outCreatingReliefSettings.widthTerrain = 2000f;
            outCreatingReliefSettings.lenghtTerrain = 2000f;
            outCreatingReliefSettings.heightTerrain = 168f;
            outCreatingReliefSettings.heightmapResoltion = 65;
            outCreatingReliefSettings.Depth = 1;
            outCreatingReliefSettings.detailResolution = 2048;
            outCreatingReliefSettings.detailResolutionPerPatch = 8;
            outCreatingReliefSettings.controlTextureResolution = 2048;
            outCreatingReliefSettings.baseTextureResolution = 2048;
            outCreatingReliefSettings.path = string.Empty;

            while (dto.reader.Read())
            {
                outCreatingReliefSettings.tileAmount = new Vector2((float)dto.reader.GetDouble(0), (float)dto.reader.GetDouble(1));
                outCreatingReliefSettings.widthTerrain = (float)dto.reader.GetDouble(2);
                outCreatingReliefSettings.lenghtTerrain = (float)dto.reader.GetDouble(3);
                outCreatingReliefSettings.heightTerrain = (float)dto.reader.GetDouble(4);
                outCreatingReliefSettings.heightmapResoltion = dto.reader.GetInt16(5);
                outCreatingReliefSettings.Depth = dto.reader.GetInt16(6);
                outCreatingReliefSettings.detailResolution = dto.reader.GetInt16(7);
                outCreatingReliefSettings.detailResolutionPerPatch = dto.reader.GetInt16(8);
                outCreatingReliefSettings.controlTextureResolution = dto.reader.GetInt16(9);
                outCreatingReliefSettings.baseTextureResolution = dto.reader.GetInt16(10);
                outCreatingReliefSettings.path = dto.reader.GetString(11);
            }
            return outCreatingReliefSettings;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public bool DeleteAllObj()
    {
        string sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM 'Textures'";
        DTO dto = DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQuery);
        if (dto != null)
        {
            if (dto.closeDataBase())
            {
                if (dto.openDataBase())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return DeleteAllObjsequence();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public bool DeleteAllObjsequence()
    {
        string sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence where name='ObjectMap'";
        DTO dto = DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQuery);
        if (dto != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public List<selectURLArrayTextures> SelectTextures(int intObj)
    {
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT id_ObjMap,id_Textures FROM Connection_ObjMap_Textures";
        DTO dto = DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQuery);
        if (dto != null)
        {
            List<selectURLArrayTextures> ListURLArray = new List<selectURLArrayTextures>();
            while (dto.reader.Read())
            {
                selectURLArrayTextures tempSelectURLArray = new selectURLArrayTextures();
                if (!dto.reader.IsDBNull(dto.reader.GetOrdinal("id_ObjMap")))
                {
                    if (intObj == dto.reader.GetInt16(0))
                    {
                        tempSelectURLArray.selectid_ObjMap = dto.reader.GetInt16(0);
                        if (!dto.reader.IsDBNull(dto.reader.GetOrdinal("id_Textures")))
                        {
                            tempSelectURLArray.selectid_Textures = dto.reader.GetInt16(1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tempSelectURLArray.selectid_Textures = -1;
                        }
                        ListURLArray.Add(tempSelectURLArray);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    tempSelectURLArray.selectid_ObjMap = -1;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < ListURLArray.Count; i++)
            {
                dto.closeDataBase();
                if (!dto.checkStatus()) { dto.openDataBase(); }
                ListURLArray[i].selectStringUrl = SetUrlClassSelectURLArrayTextures(ListURLArray[i].selectid_Textures);
                dto.closeDataBase();
            }
            return ListURLArray;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private string SetUrlClassSelectURLArrayTextures(int id_pref_int)
    {
        string tempstring = "";
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT url FROM Textures WHERE id_tex = '" + id_pref_int + "'";
        DTO dto = DEMO.Common.DTOSerializerHelper.SerializeDTO(this, sqlQuery);
        if (dto != null)
        {
            while (dto.reader.Read())
            {
                if (!dto.reader.IsDBNull(dto.reader.GetOrdinal("url")))
                {
                    tempstring = dto.reader.GetString(0);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    tempstring = "";
                }
            }
            return tempstring;
        }
        else
        {
            return tempstring;
        }
    }
}
```